# Node JS + Express : Render subviews in a main view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I've got a page which is "Google Card" designed. I want to render some views on the cards of this main page.

The Cards interface looks like this:
[image]

Because there can be many cards, I organized my project in modules.

(BTW, if you know a framework thats fits more my project than Express does, can you tell it to me? :) )

I'm using Node.js with the Express Framework. My directory structures is this:

```
|-app
|--modules
|---weather
|---index.js
|----views
|-----weather.jade
|--views
|--config.js
|--server.js
|-public
|--assets
|---img
|---css
|---...
```

Here is some of my current code:

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

Board = {};

Board.modules = {};
Board.modules.weather = require('./modules/weather');

app.use(Board.modules.sticks);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    tpl = {};
    tpl.modules = Board.modules;
    console.log(tpl);
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/board.jade', tpl);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

board.jade (the main page)

```
doctype html
html(lang="fr")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title Board
    block stylesheets
      link(rel="stylesheet", href="/public/assets/css/reset.css")
      link(rel="stylesheet", href="/public/assets/css/board.css")
  body
    // Background
    div.bg

    // Header
    header.topinfo
      span.left.ip
        | 192.168.31.11
      span.center.logo
        span.logo
          span.logo-baseline
      span.right.time
        | 13:37

      // Modules
      ul
        each val in modules
          li= val

     block scripts
        script(src="/public/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")
        script(src="/public/assets/lib/jquery-taphold/taphold.js")
        script(src="/public/assets/lib/background-check/background-check.min.js")
        script(src="/public/assets/bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js")
        script(src="/public/assets/js/app.js")
```

And the modules/weather/index.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/sticks.jade');
});
```

I think the purpose would be like getting the result of the app.get('/') of modules/weather/index.js, but without calling the route, to after insert the result of the rendering into the main view, but I don't know how to do that keeping the modularity of my code...

Comment: you've defined 2 app.get('/'), so it maybe conflict. why don't you try :`app.get('/') -> res.render('/index.jade'); app.get('/weather') -> res.render('/sticks.jade')` and
in the `index.jade` has js script call ajax `$get({url :'/weather'})` and fill data to a class such as `<div class="weather-stick"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, pass your main app to your modules, don't create 2 express apps, you can handle the rest using routes.

You should create a small API and use AJAX calls to fill up your main view :

On the server side :

```
app.get('/weather', function(req,res){
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/sticks.jade');
});
```

Client jade:

```
div#weather
```

Client JS (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({ url: '/weather',
     type: 'get',
     success: function(view) {
       $('#weather').html(view);
     }
});
```

Comment: I didn't even thought about AJAX... ! Thanks a lot xShirase and Jh Kaiz !

Comment: But what do you mean by "Don't create 2 express apps", do you have a sample of code ?

Comment: Basically, the code above replaces your modules/weather/index.js. By defining a /weather route in the main app, you  don't need to create another one in the weather directory

Answer (score 0):

@xShirase

> First, pass your main app to your modules, don't create 2 express apps

As far as I know, modules in node are cached, meaning, that when you require express in sub-files, you actually get exactly the same instance as in the main app.js/server.js. So passing app doesn't improve anything, but imo makes it a tiny bit uglier.